# CSS Tabs remove bottom border on active tab, while having a background image and having rounded borders on content

Tags: html, css, tabs

I want to implement a tab menu that is similar to the following image but with a background-image instead of a fixed background-color:
[image]

In order to achieve the rounded border of the content I had to add the border of tabs in the content ( border-top ) and in order to hide the border on the active tab I had a border on bottom of the active tab with the same color as the background. Now that I need to add a background-image this solution does not work.

I already tried similar solutions like using the :before, :after pseudo-class  to add a fake border before and after the active tab but I lose the functionality of border-radius.

Current implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-wright-13kwl7?file=/index.html

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: @tatactic added current implementation to the question

Comment: Do you mean that when tab is active you want to assign a background image to that tab?

Comment: @NehaSoni No. I want to hide the "bottom border" on the active tab but due to the dynamic background I can't do that. I have a codesandbox link that shows the issue ( a black line under the active tab. )